# Software that can change pitch of all sounds produced by PC in real time on a per-channel basis [Windows or Linux]

Tags: audio, device-driver

I have a condition called diplacusis where one ear perceives the frequency or pitch of sounds differently than the other. Even if both earbuds are playing the same note, I will hear a different pitch in one of my ears. As a music lover this poses a slight annoyance that I would like to correct if possible. Of course any answers would be helpful for others with other motives as well.

I have looked, unsuccessfully, for software or drivers that can alter the frequency of every sound played by my PC in real time at all times, selectively for each stereo channel. Most recommendations are for real time left/right volume balance or post-production pitch correction audio software. Nothing is live and global like I need.

My PC's driver doesn't offer this option, as far as I can tell.

Any ideas?

I use Windows 7 and Windows 10, software compatible with either of those would be appropriate. I might switch to Linux in the medium future so recommendations for Linux will eventually be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test any of this, I'm not on Windows, but have a look at [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) & their other apps. You need to be able to split the audio stream & affect one side only. I know how to do this easily on Mac [with paid software], but not any other platform.

As far as I can see, VB can use VST format plugins. I can't figure whether it can split the stream.

Then it's just a case of finding the right pitch-shifter - a few here https://producelikeapro.com/blog/best-pitch-shifter-vsts-2021/ [I only know the expensive ones, the free ones are a mystery to me as to how good each may be.]

btw, I can appreciate how you feel. I once had the condition temporarily, one ear was nearly a semitone out from the other… rough when you're trying to sing :\